# instance_eval is deprecated, what is the replacement?

Tags: ruby

Documentation states `instance_eval` is deprecated:

> http://apidock.com/ruby/Object/instance_eval
>
> Method deprecated or moved
> This method is deprecated or moved on the latest stable version. The last existing version (v1_8_7_330) is shown here.
>
> These similar methods exist in v1_9_3_392:
>
> BasicObject#instance_eval

What should we use instead?

Comment: Isn't it just saying it was moved to `BasicObject` instead of `Object`?

Comment: Apidock's deprecation notices are frequently wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep using it. The documentation says that `Object#instance_eval` was replaced by `BasicObject#instance_eval`. `BasicObject` was introduced recently. There would be no change under ordinary use.

Comment: Got it! Thank you for explaining.